# How to Convert given date into readable format in android

Tags: android, date

I am doing Json parsing and retrieving a `Date` from it. I am getting in this format `2012-07-24` but i want to display it in this format `Tuesday July 24, 2012`.

Can anybody suggest how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
String s;
Format formatter;
                  //  vvvvvvvvvv  Add your date object here
Date date = new Date("2012-07-24");

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy");
s = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: If you appreciate with my help then you can upvote and accept OLDEST Answer!!! @user1530732

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to parse and format the date. On the JavaDoc are lots of examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
    String date = "2012-07-24";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy");
        date = df2.format(format.parse(yourdate));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this below method

```
 SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 SimpleDateFormat dfDate_day= new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy");

 public String formatTimeDay(String str)
 {
    java.util.Date d = null;

    try {
        d = dfDate.parse(str);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    str = dfDate_day.format(d);

    return str;
}
```

> usage ====> formatTimeDay("2012-07-24");

Here

```
EEEE =====> day name (like Sunday, Monday)
MMMM =====> month name(like January, March)
dd   =====> day number of the present month
yyyy =====> present year
```

Comment: Nice answer. Now i can convert date in any format. Really Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SimpleDateFormat for this purpose, do as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat smf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dt=smf.parse(strDate, 0);
smf= new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd,yyyy");
String newFt=smf.format(dt);
```