# Completely reformat a String? - Android

Tags: android, json, string, datetime, format

Currently i am pulling data from an API and loading it into my App. It comes in JSON and a particular string is very ugly to look at. I'm looking to be able to rearrange/reformat this String to make it more pleasing. It's a date/time String.

I've had a look around and have found a few different possibilities, but it's not efficient at all.

**Example of what i get, and what i'm after...**

**JSON**: 2016-06-23T02:55:14.907

**Formatted:** 23/06/2016 - 02:55

Anything along those lines, or just in general. I'm just looking for suggestions of ways i might be able to do it. I'm still fairly new to Android. Anything you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 28/06/2016**

Here is what i'm doing

dateJSON is: 2016-06-01T21:00:00

```
public String convertDate(String dateJSON) {

    String convertedDate = "";
    Format formatter;

    Date date = new Date(dateJSON);

    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm");
    convertedDate = formatter.format(date);

    return convertedDate;

}
```

**Edit - Solved**

```
public String convertDate(String dateJSON) {

    String holder = dateJSON;

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm");
        convertedDate = format2.format(format.parse(holder));
        return convertedDate;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertedDate;
}
```

Better explanation below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629137/how-to-convert-given-date-into-readable-format-in-android

Comment: I didn't think this would work as it's a String given from JSON, not a date? I'll give it a go and see what happens though. Thank you!

Comment: just pass your json date as a new date.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: 2016-06-01T21:00:00 

I'm getting this :(

Comment: how did you pass the date? check this stack overflow page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004460/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-in-date-java

Comment: Refer to the edit above. Apologies for the hassle.

Comment: Found the answer in the original linked threat. Edited Slightly. Refer above. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Noodelz If you found the answer, please post is here as the answer, not edit, and mark it resolved

Comment: Done :) (I have to wait two days before i can mark it resolved)

Comment: @Noodelz, That's great. Sorry I wasnt much help.

Comment: You were great help! Without you, i wouldn't have found that comment in the linked thread :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer below:

I have passed the string containing the date from JSON into this method.
If you change 'format' to match the date you're passing in (in this case it matches my dateJSON variable), and then set 'format2' to the format you're after on output :)

```
public String convertDate(String dateJSON) {

String holder = dateJSON;

try {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm");
    convertedDate = format2.format(format.parse(holder));
    return convertedDate;
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return convertedDate;}
```